# Is there a way to use Weights and Biases with Optuna?

Tags: optimization, deep-learning

Is there a way to use Weights and Biases with Optuna? I tried resulted in the error

> weights and biases backend has shutdown

Comment: please add more details and snippets if you can

Comment: Not sure about your question. W&B is integrated with Optuna, check this [blog post](https://www.h4pz.co/blog/2020/10/3/optuna-and-wandb). Also check out this [code](https://github.com/optuna/optuna/blob/0cdabb841e5bf912da5d26b1680c6d999cee1958/optuna/integration/wandb.py) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Also, there is a [Weights & Biases callback](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.integration.WeightsAndBiasesCallback.html#optuna.integration.WeightsAndBiasesCallback) in the latest release of Optuna:

Minimal code:

```py
import optuna
from optuna.integration.wandb import WeightsAndBiasesCallback


def objective(trial):
    x = trial.suggest_float("x", -10, 10)
    return (x - 2) ** 2


wandb_kwargs = {"project": "my-project"}
wandbc = WeightsAndBiasesCallback(wandb_kwargs=wandb_kwargs)


study = optuna.create_study(study_name="my_study")
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=10, callbacks=[wandbc])
```

Comment: nice! also there is a [callback in optuna](https://github.com/optuna/optuna/blob/0cdabb841e5bf912da5d26b1680c6d999cee1958/optuna/integration/wandb.py)  that makes this straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

It works given that we use it with a single process.
You've to make n_jobs = 1.
Otherwise I always eventually ran into some initialization error from the wandb's side.